# Swift Function Syntax Breakdown

Tags: swift, syntax

I apologize in advance for the title of this question.

I'm hoping to get a breakdown on some syntax elements of a function in Swift.

The function:

```
let call:NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        println("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    println("response = \(response)")
}
```

What I'm wondering is line by line, how do the elements effect the constant?

What I see;

1) A constant being set to be the result of a function (`session.dataTaskWithR...`) with a "request" parameter followed by what seems to be the beginning of a closure function `{` to execute when triggered. (with `call.resume()`)

2) Are these declared variables for the function?  Are they being assigned here?  Seems weird to just write "data,response,error" at the top of a function or object, I assume/know these are populated with data returned from the `session.dataTas..` call.  It just seems as though they are undeclared and not typed.

4) This seems pretty straight forward that if error is not nil, print the error and exit.

9) print the response headers.

So, I guess my main question is regarding line 2.  I see no meaning to just writing variable names other than, that's just how it is done.  Is this just how it's done?

Comment: Look up "Closure Expression Syntax", "Trailing Closures" and "Inferring Type From Context" in the Swift book. It is all documented ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the word "closure" wrong. All functions are closures in Swift. What makes this function special is that is *anonymous*. That means there is no declaration line — so there needs to be another way of expressing the incoming parameters. Swift's solution is that you put the parameter list (and, perhaps, the return type) in an `in` line at the start of the function body.

> Seems weird to just write "data,response,error" at the top of a function or object, I assume/know these are populated with data returned from the session.dataTas.. call. It just seems as though they are undeclared and not typed.

Correct. They *can* be typed explicitly, but they don't have to be in *this* case, because the types are already known to the compiler; it already knows what the parameters of `session.dataTaskWithRequest:` are (including the types of the parameters of the function that it takes as its second parameter).

Comment: For full details, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions

Comment: This answer is a little bit like a closure in that it depends on the context provided by the [tag:swift] tag. For the sake of clarity, you might want to add *in Swift*, because in other languages functions are not necessarily closures.

Comment: @Caleb fair enough, will do. However, your witticism "This answer is a little bit like a closure" is too clever for me. :)))

Answer (score 1):

> I see no meaning to just writing variable names other than, that's just how it is done. Is this just how it's done?

This is one way that it *can be* done. See the section *Inferring Type From Context* in the [*Closures*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) section of *The Swift Programming Language*:

*It is always possible to infer the parameter types and return type when passing a closure to a function as an inline closure expression. As a result, you never need to write an inline closure in its fullest form when the closure is used as a function argument.*

Because the method declaration looks like this:

```
func dataTaskWithRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest,
       completionHandler completionHandler: ((NSData!,
                                  NSURLResponse!,
                                  NSError!) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

the compiler can infer the types of the `data`, `response`, and `error` parameters and also the return type.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs, the Swift signature for that method is

```
func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest,
       completionHandler completionHandler: ((NSData!,
                                  NSURLResponse!,
                                  NSError!) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

It takes 2 parameters, and NSURLRequest and a completion block.

Swift has a special-case optional way to handle invoking a method who's last parameter is a closure, known as a "Trailing closure".

You can pass the closure as a parameter inside the parentheses like normal, or you can skip the label (`completionHandler`) and simply add the braces for the closure after the parens.

I don't think this bit:

```
data, response, error in
```

is valid syntax.

```
(data, response, error) -> () in
```

It tells you that the closure takes 3 input parameters and returns void (nothing.)

### EDIT:

Matt reports in his comments that it IS legal syntax, although I still don't understand how it's legal without the parentheses around the parameters. I'm awaiting clarification with interest.

The closure takes an NSData, an NSURLResponse, and an NSURL, all force-unwrapped optionals.

Comment: @Matt, I understand that you know more about Swift than I do. You've been working on it longer than I. I worded that part of my answer the way I did because I wasn't sure if that syntax was legal or not. I wanted to avoid an  absolute "that syntax isn't legal" statement because I wasn't sure. Your "what looks legal to you is of no interest" comment is arrogant, snide, and dismissive. Let's maintain a level of professionalism, shall we?

Comment: Apology accepted. Can you explain how it's legal without the parentheses around the parameters?

Comment: I clicked the link and looked pretty carefully through the relevant section, but did not find anything about skipping the parentheses on the parameters. Skipping the `-> ()` for the closure result, yes, but not the parentheses on the parameters.

Comment: @Matt, I edited my answer to make it clear that my question about the syntax was my (less than expert) understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79149/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-matt).